# Most reliable framework for classic asp, jquery, and Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

Looking to supplement an asp application that already does complicated form postbacks so I don't have to add any more weird conditionals to the form post vars. What is the most reliable way to do something like update a field in a database on a button click and return a success or fail code? Thinking jquery because user might be in ie safari chrome or fox. But should be fox mostly.

Comment: Are you after a sort of an AJAX based solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at some of the existing classic asp frameworks and take the best pieces away from them:

- [ASP Extreme Evolution (AXE)](http://zend.lojcomm.com.br/entries/meet-asp-xtreme-evolution/)
- [Ajaxed](http://www.ajaxed.org/)